# Paginar en Dingo Api con Laravel 5.3 en una relación morphMany

Tags: php, laravel, api

He llevado dias tratando de realizar dicha paginación en todos los ejemplos que e puesto ninguno me a dado resultado. La librería que uso es la de Dingo Api con [fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/). La paginación es la siguiente:

Paginar el listado de comentarios de un Stream (Post) que se muestra en el Timeline del usuario, yo lo estuve realizando de esta manera y no a dado resultados solo del Stream que si me da la paginación dejo el codigo para ser revisado

Controller: **HomeController**

```
   public function index()
    {
        $stream = Stream::with('users', 'type','comments', 'comments.users', 'upload', 'likes')->where(function ($query){
            $query->where('users_type', 'stream');
        })->paginate(2);

        return $this->response->paginator($stream, new StreamTransformer());
    }
```

El resultado Json es el siguiente con **Postman**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "stream_id": 2,
      "stream_body": "http://www.taringa.net/posts/info/19614066/8-cursos-online-gratuitos-para-mejorar-tu-Ingles.html",
      "stream_type": "link",
      "stream_user": 1,
      "stream_privacy": "public",
      "stream_created_at": "hace 3 días",
      "stream_hace": 1476134236,
      "users": {
        "data": {
          "user_name": "vdjkelly",
          "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
        }
      },
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "comment_body": "dasdasdas",
            "comment_stream_id": 2,
            "comment_user_id": 1,
            "users": {
              "data": {
                "user_name": "vdjkelly",
                "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "comment_body": "dsadad",
            "comment_stream_id": 2,
            "comment_user_id": 1,
            "users": {
              "data": {
                "user_name": "vdjkelly",
                "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "comment_body": "fdsffs",
            "comment_stream_id": 2,
            "comment_user_id": 1,
            "users": {
              "data": {
                "user_name": "vdjkelly",
                "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "comment_body": "sdasdasdas",
            "comment_stream_id": 2,
            "comment_user_id": 1,
            "users": {
              "data": {
                "user_name": "vdjkelly",
                "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "comment_body": "sdasdd",
            "comment_stream_id": 2,
            "comment_user_id": 1,
            "users": {
              "data": {
                "user_name": "vdjkelly",
                "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total": 7,
      "count": 1,
      "per_page": 1,
      "current_page": 2,
      "total_pages": 7,
      "links": {
        "previous": "http://timeline.dev/api/home?page=1",
        "next": "http://timeline.dev/api/home?page=3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Los comentarios a mostrar 5 de acuerdo al include que le hago en el Transformer StreamTransformer

```
class StreamTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'users', 'comments'
    ];

    protected $defaultIncludes = [
        'users', 'comments'
    ];

    public function transform(Stream $stream)
    {

        return [
            'stream_id' => $stream->id,
            'stream_body' => $stream->body,
            'stream_type' => $stream->stream_type,
            'stream_user' => $stream->user_id,
            'stream_privacy' => $stream->privacy,
            'stream_created_at' => $stream->created_at,
            'stream_hace' => $stream->p_hace
        ];
    }
    public function includeUsers(Stream $stream)
    {
        $users = $stream->users;
        return $this->item($users, new UserTransformer);
    }

    public function includeComments(Stream $stream)
    {
        $cmt = $stream->comments()->paginate(5);
        return $this->collection($cmt, new CommentTransformer());
    }


}
```

Deberían de mostrase paginados los comentarios ya que ese Stream (Post) tiene mas de 8 comentarios solo me limita mas no me los pagina como debería ser para accesar a ellos a través de un link en especifico como por ejemplo

```
"comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "comment_body": "dasdasdas",
            "comment_stream_id": 2,
            "comment_user_id": 1,
            "users": {
              "data": {
                "user_name": "vdjkelly",
                "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "comment_body": "dsadad",
            "comment_stream_id": 2,
            "comment_user_id": 1,
            "users": {
              "data": {
                "user_name": "vdjkelly",
                "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "comment_body": "fdsffs",
            "comment_stream_id": 2,
            "comment_user_id": 1,
            "users": {
              "data": {
                "user_name": "vdjkelly",
                "user_email": "vdjkelly@gmail.com"
              }
            }
          },

        ] 
"meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total": 9,
      "count": 1,
      "per_page": 1,
      "current_page": 2,
      "total_pages": 9,
      "links": {
        "previous": "http://timeline.dev/api/home?stream_id=2&comment_include&page=1",
        "next": "http://timeline.dev/api/home?stream_id=2&comment_include&page=2"
      }
    }
  }
```

Asi poder realizar la paginacion por medio de ajax

Comment: ¿Necesitas eso en una consulta? ¿Puedes hacerlo en dos?

Comment: Ya lo hice necesitaba que los stream paginaran el limite que yp quisiera al igual que los comentarios de cada stream